# CS224(2021) self study question about transformer on random keys

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, normal-distribution, natural-language, transformers

I am self studying the famous Stanford class CS224 about NLP. I am struggling to make a "formal" argument with a question involving multivariate gaussian distribution even though I get intuitively what is going on. Here is the question:

[image]

I see that in point ii, the problem is that the output $c$ can be quite different depending on the noise distribution (closer to $v_a$ than to $v_b$ depending on the norm of the key, but I cannot make a formal argument about it. Any points & help would be greatly appreciated :)

Many thanks.